# How to connect python to sqlite3 and fill multiple row in once

Tags: python, sqlite

this is my code

```
#!usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import sqlite3
import os, sys, subprocess
import numpy as np 
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import Medline

Entrez.email = "shayezkarimcide@gmail.com"

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pmc", 
term = "Antimicrobial resistance",
rettype = "medline",retmode = "txt",
retmax= '10',sort = "pub date")

result = Entrez.read(handle)

handle.close()

Id = result ['IdList']


print (list(Id), "\n")
rint ("The length of PubId is :",len(Id))


conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/cbbi-l2-16/Desktop/karim')
c = conn.cursor()

print ("Opened database successfully")

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Entrez (PuId) VALUES (?)", Id)

for row in c :
print (row)
conn.commit()

print ("Records Save Successfully")

conn.close()?
```

it give Error

File "sqlpython.py", line 42, in 
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO Entrez (PuId) VALUES (?)", Id)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 7 supplied.

Comment: Please show what you get for `print(result ['IdList'])`

Comment: At a guess, you want `c.executemany("INSERT INTO Entrez (PuId) VALUES (?)", [[x] for x in Id])`

Comment: print (result['IdList'])   it will give research article no  bunch

Answer (score 0):

just add `?` as many arguments that are in `Id`.

according to sqlite3 docs :

> Put ? as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s execute() method.

according to the docs this should be the case in `executemany` as well, take a look at this example taken from the docs:

> Larger example that inserts many records at a time
>
> purchases = 
>   [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
>
> ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
>
> ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
>               ]
>
> c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)

Comment: This is incorrect. The OP is not using `execute`, they are trying to use `executemany`; they only want to insert a single value per row but repeat this many times. It's not a case of adding more placeholders because that will apply to a single row

Comment: here is the example from the sqlite3 docs to python 2.7 `# Larger example that inserts many records at a time
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)`

Comment: Yes, but if you want to only insert one parameter _per line_ then you do _not_ add as many `?` as there are items in your outer list. What if I wanted to insert 10,000 rows? Should I supply 10K `?`?

Comment: In other words, the OP has one _column_ in their table and they want to insert seven _rows_ into that column. They are correct in only using a single placeholder in their `executemany` call.